# Running multiple instances of spring batch job in parallel

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, spring-batch-tasklet

I have a Job for monthly invoicing. Current job consist from few Steps. I am passing data between Steps  using `StepExecution` and `ExecutionContextPromotionListener`. We are going to run Job for each invoice. So we will have multiple instances of a job in parallel which pass data between Steps .

```
implements ItemWriter<Invoice> {
 @BeforeStep
  public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
  }
}

@Bean
  public ExecutionContextPromotionListener promotionListener() {
    ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener = new ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
    listener.setKeys(new String[] {"invoice"});
    return listener;
  }
```

I am pretty sure it`s not thread safe. Could somebody advise any solution for Spring Batch?

Any advice or explanation if I am wrong